# How do I align a Logo next to navigation links that are horizontally centered?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been struggling the last several hours with positioning my logo just to the right of the centered navigation links in a responsive Navbar.   Tried dozens of ways to get this to work without any luck.  I left most of the CSS for the Navbar intact; BootStrap 3.  Any assistance would be greatly 
appreciated!  Link to site is:

Many Thanks!

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="indexalt.html">
      <img src="data2/test5.png" width="61" height="48">
    </a>
    <div class="navbar-text"> <span class="FutureFont">Future Youth <span style="color:#ee1b04; font-size: 16px;">R</span>ecords</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <a href="OurTeam.html">NEWS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="AboutUs.html" class="dropdown-toggle">ABOUT US</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="OurTeam.html">Our Team</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Mission</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a>
      </li>

      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">MEDIA</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Audio</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Video</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Photos</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Enter Download Code</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">DONATE</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
    </span>


    <div class="sociallinks pull-right">
      <a href="">
        <img id="aks" src="data2/FB1.png" width="32" height="32">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img id="akst" src="data2/Twitter1.png" width="32" height="32">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img id="aksy" src="data2/youtube1.png" width="32" height="32">
      </a>
      </span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: share the html please

Comment: You want the future youth record logo to be there instead of the Social Media links (e.g. FB, Twitter)?

Comment: Thank you for responding, adding the Html momentarily.   I've just uploaded an image showing how I would like it to look...   www.futureyouthrecords.org/test002.png    The Logo, Links and Social Icons should all be centered; when the navbar collapses just the Logo should show and the Links and Social should become part of the toggled navigation.  I’m pretty sure I can get the social links correct, but the Logo has me completely bewildered.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your html had unclosed divs, extra divs, wrong classes, and lots of issues. It's best to follow examples on the GetBootstrap.com to the letter and comment and indent your code. When you have a problem that requires getting help, always make an effort to use clean, valid, html with following the documentation.**

The .navbar for Bootstrap is very specific, it's left or right and that's it. You have to understand CSS and positioning etc., to change it around. And you also have to be adept at responsive CSS and become very fluent with the Bootstrap CSS as well.

This is not the finished product. The height of the navbar in this situation is dependent on the height of the tallest child, the logo. The logo is 60px tall with 10px padding on the top and bottom, 80px line-height on the first child of the links is used to make it center inside there. Otherwise there would be a lot more CSS to create.

[image]

### DEMO: https://jsbin.com/tupay/1/

*https://jsbin.com/tupay/1/edit?html,css,output*

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar-center navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="nav">
   <div class="container">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="logo" href="indexalt.html">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/ffffff/000000&text=LOGO">
      </a>
      <div id="navbar" class="my-collapse collapse">
         <ul class="navbar-center navbar-nav nav">
            <li>
               <a href="OurTeam.html">NEWS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
               <a href="AboutUs.html" class="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown">ABOUT US <span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="OurTeam.html">Our Team</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Mission</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
               <!--/.dropdown-menu -->
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">MEDIA <span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Audio</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Video</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Photos</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Enter Download Code</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
               <!--/.dropdown-menu -->
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">DONATE</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
         <!-- /ul.navbar-center -->
      </div>
      <!--/.my-collapse collapse -->
      <div class="social-links clearfix">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64/ffffff/000000&text=X">
         </a>
         <a href="#">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64/ffffff/000000&text=X">
         </a>
         <a href="#">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64/ffffff/000000&text=X">
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--/.social-links -->
   </div>
   <!--/.container -->
</nav>
<!-- /nav.navbar-center -->
```

**CSS**

```
nav.navbar-center.navbar-inverse {
    background: #000
}
.navbar-center .social-links a {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
nav.navbar-center .social-links {
    float: left;
    padding: 27px 0 10px 0;
}
nav.navbar-center img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
nav.navbar-center .logo {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 0;
}
.navbar-inverse button.navbar-toggle {
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 80px;
}
.navbar-inverse button.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 0;
    background:#fff;
    border:0px;
    padding: 0;
}
@media (max-width:767px) { 
    nav.navbar-center .my-collapse {
        clear: both;
        padding: 10px 0;
    }
}
@media (min-width:768px) { 
    nav.navbar-center img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    nav.navbar-center .container {
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 980px;
    }
    #navbar.my-collapse.collapse {
        visibility: visible;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    ul.navbar-center > li > a {
        padding: 0 15px;
        line-height: 80px;
    }
    nav.navbar-center .logo {
        padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
        text-align: left;
        float: left;
    }
    nav.navbar-center .social-links {
        line-height: 80px;
        float: right;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to work out the coding Christina, I really appreciate it!  I think I have a better understanding of it now, and will definitely make sure I clean up the code for any future requests.

Comment: Cool. Please select it as the answer so others can find it.